# 3D jogl application hangs when using awt TextRenderer

Tags: java, text, rendering, jogl, textrenderer

I am trying to make my custom GUI inside OpenGL aplication. I would like to use TextRenderer class to render texts for me. But when I use it I notice a strange behavior. The aplication runs smoothly for about minute or two then starts to lag and is practicaly unusable. I figured out that this only happenes when I put TextRenderer in place. So it must be something how I use TextRenderer. I have looked at my code, at itss code, and didn't find anything obvious.

My architecture goes like this:

```
class BaseUIElement
{
    protected TextRenderer textRenderer;

    //something something

    public BaseUIElement ()
    {
        //something something

        this.textRenderer = new TextRenderer(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 16) );
    }

    public final void Render( GL2 gl)
    {
        //setting ortho projection, binding textures for menu and stuff

        this.drawContent();

        //restoring OGL states to before
    }

    protected void drawContent()
    {
        //box itself drawing magics

        textRenderer.beginRendering(...);            

        this.textRenderer.setColor(...);

         for (String line : textLines) 
         {
             this.textRenderer.draw( ... );
         }

         this.textRenderer.endRendering();
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
        //free my stuff

        this.textRenderer.dispose();
    }
}
```

I also used properties of text renderer to determin text align box size and stuff but I dot thinl thats relevant. 
One thing you will most likely point out is, that I shouldn't have constructed UIElemetn in each call of OpenGL display loop. But If that was the problem, I would expect the App to run slow from the very begining. And I do call destroy() after I am done with each UI object so the TextRenderer should free the resources each time. I didn't took a look at memory usage and there is nothing strange about it. The heap size stays basicly the same whole time. 
Any cluses what I should have a look at or what may be the problem?
I would do more, but I am not sure how to debug this behavior.
I would be glad for any advice. :)

Comment: Instead of making speculations, please provide a sscce: http://sscce.org I advise you to use a profiler to determine what becomes slow after one minute.